# Angular material matNoDataRow doesn't work in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

In `mat-table`, I need to show a message when no data matches. For this, I am using `*matNoDataRow` directive but it doesn't work. Somewhere, I read that it doesn't work in Angular version below 10. But, mine is Angular11, still it is not working.

Below is my HTML snippet:

```
<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
     <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching with Appt. Id "{{ input.value }}"</td>
</tr>
```

Am I doing something wrong in it?

Comment: Please, reproduce your issue on stackblitz with more details. I just added matNoDataRow to sample stackblitz using Angular 11 and it works perfectly fine, so the issue is somewhere else in your code. Stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2p4zwk

Comment: @TotallyNewb I found my glitch. I placed `*matNoDataRow` outside of the `mat-table`. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `mat-table` together with `tr` and `td`. You need to use either both `table` and `tr/td` or `mat-table` and `mat-row`/`mat-cell`.
That should work.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Take a look at examples: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: In the example they used table with tr/td which is working. But I suppose the author wanted to use that inside an mat-table used as an html tag. mat-table as html tag only works with mat-row mat-cell as html tags.